# disable typeahead angular controller dependent on user setting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I would like to disable the typeahead feature when a user has a checkbox checked in a settings menu (id = searchSuggestions). The code below works only upon a fresh reload of the page, but not during a session. Is it possible to disable angular's typeahead implementation during a session? If so, how?

```
// Controller for Angular's Search implementation
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    // prefetch the results
    var value = $('#searchSuggestions').is(':checked');
    if (value == true) {
      $.getJSON('/typeahead', function(response){
        //parse your response and assign it
        $scope.recentPopularQueries = response;
       });

      // Fire off the transcribe(words) function as soon as a choice is selected
      $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
        $scope.$label = $label;
        transcribe($scope.$label);
      };
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a checkbox with a scope model:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="typeaheadActive">
```

Add the model value to your condition before doing the typeahead request:

```
// Controller for Angular's Search implementation
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    // prefetch the results
    var value = $('#searchSuggestions').is(':checked');
    if (value == true && typeaheadActive) {
        $.getJSON('/typeahead', function(response) {
            //parse your response and assign it
            $scope.recentPopularQueries = response;
        });

        // Fire off the transcribe(words) function as soon as a choice is selected
        $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
            $scope.$label = $label;
            transcribe($scope.$label);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks straightforward! However, now it complains that it doesn't recognize typeaheadActive:
    ReferenceError: typeaheadActive is not defined

Comment: try define `typeahead = true;` at the beginning of your controller.